# How to make background colours on labels/ buttons translucent Python

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, label

im designing a login screen that has a photo in the background, i want users to be able to see everyone behind the photo. so i want to add translucent backgrounds so that you can see people but you can still know where the button is

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want? To me it seems you want a color background for any widget. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To add a color background to any widget, you should use the `bg` parameter. It works for almost all widgets.

Here is an example for adding a blue background to a button:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
button1 = Button(window, text = "button", bg = "blue").pack()
window.mainloop()
```

In this example, you get this output: [image: output]

The option is also there to add hex codes in place of the word:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
button1 = Button(window, text = "button", bg = "#45a34e").pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Output: 
[image: output number 2]

Hopefully this is what you were looking for!!